# Вы и вы: как же правильно?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Здравствуйте!
Хочу узнать мнение специалистов. Я являюсь копирайтером одного серьезного ресурса, где в статьях нередко идет обращение к читателю типа "У нас вы можете получить документы быстро и недорого". Я настаиваю на том, что "вы" в данном случае пишется с маленькой буквы, потому что мы не знает конкретного читателя, к которому обращаемся. Начальство же настаивает на обратном: "Мы уважаем каждого пользователя и обращаемся лично к нему".
Рассудите нас, пожалуйста, кто все-таки прав?

Answer (score 3):

***Вы строчная*** используется в следующих случаях.

> .при обращении к нескольким лицам в частной и деловой переписке: «Прошу вас, уважаемый Сергей Петрович и Иван Васильевич…»; «Господа, ваше письмо…»;
>
> .в газетных публикациях, в рекламе;
>
> в литературных произведениях (диалог, прямая речь, личное обращение):

«…Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит. Я не хочу печалить вас ничем»;

> при цитировании;
>
> ***при обращении к пользователю на web-странице;***
>
> если обращение гипотетическое, то и в письме: «Уважаемый коллега! По поводу высказанного вами предположения…»

***«Словарь трудностей русского языка» Д.Э.Розенталя и М.А.Теленковой. 
«Прописная или строчная?» В.В.Лопатина***

Подробнее можете прочитать здесь: [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_88)

А вот ответ Граммы.ру.

Ответ: Употребление местоимения «Вы» с прописной буквы как форма вежливого обращения характерно именно тогда, когда речь идет об обращении к конкретному лицу - хотя даже в этом случае возможно употребление «вы» со строчной буквы, если, например, нет необходимости подчеркивать «официальность» обращения. Разумеется, если «сообщение электронной почты» направляется конкретному лицу, вполне возможно (и чаще всего даже необходимо) писать «Вы» именно с прописной. Но если в таком электронном письме содержится, например, рекламное объявление, обращенное к обобщенному адресату, то местоимение «вы» следует писать со строчной.Только вышедший из печати «Толковый словарь русского речевого этикета» также отмечает, что по общему правилу местоимения Вы и Ваш пишутся с прописной буквы как форма выражения вежливости при обращении к одному лицу - физическому или юридическому - в официальных документах, личных письмах. Однако в эпистолярной практике и в печати это правило не всегда строго соблюдается. ***Регулярно прописная буква употребляется при подчеркнуто вежливом обращении в поздравительных адресах и открытках, в письмах к незнакомому или малознакомому адресату, равному или старшему по возрасту, положению, а также в официально-деловой корреспонденции.***

Comment: Вот именно, что мне привели цитату из грамоты.ру как подтверждение того, что надо писать с большой буквы. Но, на мой взгляд, грамота.ру однозначного ответа не дает.

Comment: Уважаемый  Shirogane, вам привели официальное правило! А цитата из Граммы лишь дополнение к ответу. Грамма ссылается на правила, которое я привел. А потом сообщает, что правило не всегда последовательно соблюдается. Какой еще ответ вам нужен?

Comment: Вот еще статья про Вы, вы. Надеюсь, поможет. [Вы, вы](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=8.24)

Comment: Кстати, цитата из Граммы, а на Грамоте изложено официальное правило.

Answer (score 2):

Начальник всегда прав, но он должен быть в курсе орфографических правил.

Нужно объяснить, что обычно в таких случаях рекомендуется использовать строчную букву, что  все и делают. Но если он хочет **особо подчеркнуть индивидуальность пользователя**, то обращение на Вы допускается, но это будет такой особой фишкой.